# Start and pipe to process such as gnuplot in F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, c#-to-f#

Essentially I want start a gnuplot process from within a .fsx script and pipe text commands to it so I can have my script replot. So far I have just been piping the stdout using the command line like this.

```
fsharpi "something.fsx" | gnuplot
```

I am doing this instead of using a plotting library because I am using gnuplot for other plots and I want the style to be the same. Also it's nice to have a lightweight solution. I am using mono on arch linux.

How can I start a gnuplot process from within a .fsx script and create a stream which allows me to pipe commands to it?

I hope that was enough detail. Thank you :)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want to know how to start a gnuplot process and create a stream to this process using commands from within an F# script. i added this to the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a semi-abandoned F# wrapper for gnuplot called [FnuPlot](http://fsprojects.github.io/FnuPlot/).

The library aimed to build a nice F#-friendly DSL for constructing GnuPlot charts, but it is very incomplete and does not cover very many of the charts and features you can use with GnuPlot.

However, it also implements some core functionality for calling GnuPlot, including starting GnuPlot, sending data to it and formatting various parameters. So, even if you cannot use the library directly, you can explore the code and use some bits of the code from there. For example [here is how it starts the gnuplot process](https://github.com/fsprojects/FnuPlot/blob/master/src/FnuPlot/FnuPlot.fs#L344) and here is [how to send data to gnuplot](https://github.com/fsprojects/FnuPlot/blob/master/src/FnuPlot/FnuPlot.fs#L344). Of course, it would be even better if you wanted to contribute and help develop and maintain the library further :-).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed :) . And of course I'll have a look to see if I can contribute